# How to check if the source is kafka or beat in logstash?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat

I have two sources of data for my logs. One is the beat and one is kafka and I want to create ES indexes based on the source. if kafka -> prefix index_name with kafka, and if beat prefix the index name with beat.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 9300
  }
}

input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["my-topic"]
    codec => json
  }
}

output {
    # if kafka
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "password"
        index  => "[kafka-topic]-my-index"
     }
    # else if beat
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "password"
        index  => "[filebeat]-my-index"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tags in your inputs and use them to filter the output.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 9300
    tags => ["beats"]
  }
}

input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["my-topic"]
    codec => json
    tags => ["kafka"]
  }
}

output {
    if "beats" in [tags] { 
        output for beats 
    }
    if "kafka" in [tags] { 
        output for kafka 
    }
}
```